# Is there a way to embed Excel functions in VBA code other than using FormulaR1C1 format?

Tags: vba

```
Range("a2") = 123.45
Range("a2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(R[-1]C,""#.00"")"
```

Can I use any other code in place of 'FormulaR1C1' and the relative reference 'R[-1]C' here?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? show an example

Comment: Well, as the code says a cell has a numerical value and it is converted to text. However the output hardly matters, What is important is: can absolute references (instead of relative reference) be used in this code?

Comment: If only absolute/relative reference matters then just remove the square brackets from [-1]. But I feel like it can't be simply that what you need...

Answer (score 0):

It's not converting the result to TEXT but try this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
    .Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
    .NumberFormat = ("0.00")
End With
```

Comment: but here's missing the `Range("a2") = 123.45 ` part of the OP's question. Which is not that clear, though. That's why I asked for clarification

Comment: Sorry, typos in the code was the root of all madness. This question may please be considered as solved and closed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My question was one step in reaching the expected result. The next step was to find out a way to use absolute rferences in loops. However,absolute references such as the one in the code:
Range("a2") = 123.45 Range("a2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(R[-1]C,""#.00"")"
are hard to manage in loops, where variables are used to get the result. After some R & D I came up with:
Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=TEXT((a1),""#.00"")" which works.
I will continue to find a way to  manipulate R1C1 formula to suit loops.

Comment: Are you trying to fill a range like A2 = TEXT(A1), B2 = TEXT(B2), C3 = TEXT(C3) as the ultimate aim, without looping?